# How to find index of the first left appearance of character that belongs to regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How to find index of the first left appearance of character that belongs to regex ?
I have arbitrary string and regex like `invalid_tail = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9+/=\n\r].*$')`
and I need to find index of character that is in invallid_tail reg.

Answer (score 2):

Use match object's `start()` method:

```
>>> text = "foobar*spam"
>>> invalid_tail = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9+/=\n\r].*$')
>>> invalid_tail.search(text).start()
6
```